# Bootstrap popover not working in some browsers

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I'm not sure if this place is the right place to ask, but i'm having trouble debugging something.

I made a website with a login functionality. When people click on login, there's a Bootstrap popover appearing with the login form.

I tested this in every browser: (IE 9,10,11 and edge + Chrome, Firefox and Safari). It works everywhere.

But, I still get messages from people that they can't login, because the login popover is not appearing. All those people are using IE.

The website i'm talking about is http://goo.gl/AZICag. Some people having trouble when they click on 'inloggen'. Unfortunately I can't simulate it the IE browsers.

the HTML is

```
    <div class="topnavform">
        <a href="#" class="usermenu" tabindex="0">
            <div class="loginwrapper">
                <span><strong>login</strong></span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="user-popover hide" id="user-popover">
            <div class="user-login">
                {{ form included with php }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the javascript is

```
    $('.usermenu').popover({ 
            html : true,
            placement: 'bottom',
            container: '.topnavform',
            template: '<div class="popover user-popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
            content: function() {
                return $('#user-popover').html();
            }
    });
```

Comment: what was the problem ? were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://www.browserstack.com/test-in-internet-explorer to check your website functionallity
hence you need to sign up to check your website

Comment: Yes, I know. But I have tested it here on my office on different PC's. (windows 10 and 7) with the internet explorer emulation tool.